# C# write new lines below existing lines

Tags: c#, csv

Say I have this csv file with a list of data that kind of looks like this:

```
"1111", "-2222", "3333"
"-4444", "5555", "-6666"
```

After messing with the data I have made them negative/positive and back into strings

```
"-1111", "2222", "-3333"
"4444", "-5555", "6666"
```

I want to write a new csv file with both sets of data, with the new data below the original data

```
"1111", "-2222", "3333"
"-4444", "5555", "-6666"

"-1111", "2222", "-3333"
"4444", "-5555", "6666"
```

I am still new to C# and I really am not the brightest when it comes to coding logics.  I tried to do it with an array list:

```
var arrList = new ArrayList();
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(currFile))
{
    string newLine = line;
    writer.WriteLine(line);
    //I'm gonna spare you the trouble to read through my terrible lines of codes to mess with the data, newLine is the string where I store the altered data
    newLine = num;
    arrList.Add(newLine);

    if (lineCount == currFile.Length-1)
    {
        writer.WriteLine("/n");
        foreach (var element in arrList)
        { 
            writer.WriteLine(element);
        }
    }
    lineCount = lineCount + 1;
}
```

But the new data isn't getting written.

Can I not detect that it is the end of the original data so that I can start writing the new one? Am I writing it wrong with `lineCount == currFile.Length-1`? Is there a better way to achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is `writer`? Please show a [mcve].

Comment: Just a tip. I usually use CsVHelper for working with CSV files.  https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started/

Comment: read the file first, then concatenate like so string theString = newCSVString + System.Environment.NewLine + theFileCSVString; in the end, save the csv file with theString var

Comment: CSV is just a text file, with Values Separated by Commas. It's not some special file format. You can use `File.AppendAllLines` to add lines to it, just like any text file. You can use a `StreamWriter` opened in `append` mode to append lines with `WriteLine` too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part to write the next lines needs to be outside of your original loop. Assuming `writer` is where you're trying to write the new file:

```
var arrList = new ArrayList();
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(currFile))
{
    writer.WriteLine(line);
    // I'm gonna spare you the trouble to read through my terrible lines of codes to mess with the data, 
    // newLine is the string where I store the altered data
    arrList.Add(newLine);

}
writer.WriteLine("/n");
foreach (var element in arrList)
{ 
     writer.WriteLine(element);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CSV files are just text files. CSV refers to their content - they contain Values Separated by Commas. You can append lines to them the same way you'd append them to any text file.

**Appending to the text file**

One way is to use [Fille.AppendAllLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendalllines?view=net-7.0) to append lines to the end of an existing file:

```
var lines=new string[]{
  "1,2,3",
  "4,5,6"
};

File.AppendAllLines(pathToFile,lines);
```

Internally, `AppendLines` uses a `StreamWriter` opened in Append mode. You can do the same in your code, to write lines directly to the file instead of storing all lines in memory:

```
using(var writer=new StreamWriter(pathToFile,true))
{
    for(......)
    {
        var line=CalculateNewLine(...);
        writer.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

Your code will have to generate each line string though and ensure each line is valid, with the same number of fields in each line and properly quoting any fields that contain commas.

**Using a CSV library**

You can use a library like [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper) to generate the strings from your application's data, taking care to properly quote and separate values. CsvHelper can append to an existing file too. The [Appending to an Existing File](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/writing/appending-to-an-existing-file/) example shows how to do that.

Let's say you have a list of Foo records

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

records = new List<Foo>
{
    new Foo { Id = 2, Name = "two" },
};
```

You can easily append them to an existing file

```
var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
{
    // Don't write the header again.
    HasHeaderRecord = false,
};
using (var stream = File.Open("path\\to\\file.csv", FileMode.Append))
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, config))
{
    csv.WriteRecords(records);
}
```

You can specify different separators, quoting rules, date and numeric formats in the configuration.